# How Runnable and Thread work

Tags: java, android, sensors, runnable, thread-sleep

I clearly misunderstand how they work. My code:

```
private final Runnable processAccel = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG, "run: AccelStart");

        registerAccel();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mHandler.postDelayed(this, interval);



        unregisterAccel();

    }
};
```

During this Runnable i was hoping to record sensor events, in the same class. However I get no data.

If I remove the

```
unregisterAccel();
```

it records data all the time, both during the runnable and when it is not running, and during when it is sleeping during the runnable, but as soon as I deregister the sensor listener at the end of the runnable, I stop getting results, even when I extend the Thread.sleep out to 10 seconds, which makes no sense to me?

Extra info:

```
public void registerAccel(){
    Log.d(TAG, "registerAccel: on");
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

}

public void unregisterAccel(){
    Log.d(TAG, "unregisterAccel: off");
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mAccelerometer);
}
```

Comment: What are you doing with `processAccel`?

Comment: It's basically the only way I can think of to try and record sensor data every 1/10 second, instead of 1/100th of a second. So I have the OnSensorChanged method, and I write the sensor data to file. I could throw away 9/10 values, but i'm trying to save battery life and be a bit more elegant

Comment: Your runnable is never run.

Comment: Sorry @Antoniossss, the Runnable is called in the Class Constructor, I just havn't included all the code, because its a big class, and my problem is something is wrong inside my Runnable method. If I remove the unRegister it works all the time, if I leave it there I never get any results, even though the sensor is registered for long periods of time

Comment: I just have no idea why runnable submits itself to be ran. It should be submitted one. It can have loop you its body you know.

Comment: Besides why it is ran in another thread? Register once, and unregister after work is done. Listenr wuill be called async.

Comment: I need to record sensor data every 1/10th of a second, Android records it every 1/100th of a second, which is too much. Basically I am trying to record a senserEvent 10 times per second.

Comment: Then register every 10th callback data. No multithreading needed.

Comment: As for your comment, IMHO what you have wrote is neither battery-saver nor elegant.

Comment: But I want to save the battery....so far I have not found a way to do it, I am thinking it is not possible to only register a sensor event every 10th of a second